# C# and REST - Deserialize JSON object with unknown nesting (type)

Tags: c#, json, rest

I consume REST API, which return JSON string.

Example of document:

```
{
  "kind": "collection#ExtendedACE",
  "selfLink": "https://1.2.3.4/api/access/in/Alohomora/rules",
  "rangeInfo": {
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 3,
    "total": 3
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "object#ExtendedACE",
      "selfLink": "https://1.2.3.4/api/access/in/Alohomora/rules/2638577060",
      "permit": false,
      "sourceAddress": {
        "kind": "AnyIPAddress",
        "value": "any"
      },
      "destinationAddress": {
        "kind": "objectRef#NetworkObj",
        "refLink": "https://1.2.3.4/api/objects/networkobjects/facebook.com",
        "objectId": "facebook.com"
      },
      "sourceService": {
        "kind": "NetworkProtocol",
        "value": "tcp"
      },
      "destinationService": [
        {
          "kind": "TcpUdpService",
          "value": "tcp/http"
        },
        {
          "kind": "TcpUdpService",
          "value": "tcp/https"
        }
      ],
      "active": true,
      "remarks": [],
      "ruleLogging": {
        "logInterval": 300,
        "logStatus": "Default"
      },
      "position": 1,
      "isAccessRule": true,
      "objectId": "2638577060"
    },
    {
      "kind": "object#ExtendedACE",
      "selfLink": "https://1.2.3.4/api/access/in/Alohomora/rules/2115120101",
      "permit": false,
      "sourceAddress": {
        "kind": "objectRef#NetworkObjGroup",
        "refLink": "https://1.2.3.4/api/objects/networkobjectgroups/Hermiona-source",
        "objectId": "Hermiona-source"
      },
      "destinationAddress": {
        "kind": "objectRef#NetworkObjGroup",
        "refLink": "https://1.2.3.4/api/objects/networkobjectgroups/Hermiona-destination",
        "objectId": "Hermiona-destination"
      },
      "sourceService": {
        "kind": "NetworkProtocol",
        "value": "icmp"
      },
      "destinationService": {
        "kind": "NetworkProtocol",
        "value": "icmp"
      },
      "active": true,
      "remarks": [
        "Test Hermiona Alohomora kouzlo"
      ],
      "ruleLogging": {
        "logInterval": 300,
        "logStatus": "Default"
      },
      "position": 2,
      "isAccessRule": true,
      "objectId": "2115120101"
    },
  ]
}
```

The problem are **destinationService**, because I dont know, how can I write the object for Deserialize.

**1/ If I use**

```
var varAccessInRulesCollection = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<RootObject>(strAccessInRulesGet).items;
```

where public class contains List

```
public class Item
    {
        ...
        public List<DestinationService> destinationService { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

the result is only the first items with collection, the second item is ignored (not parsed)

**2/ If I use**

```
var varAccessInRulesCollection = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<RootObject>(strAccessInRulesGet).items;
```

where public class contains object

```
public class Item
    {
        ...
        public object destinationService { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

the result is only the second items as array, the first item is ignored (not parsed)

Exists some code, how  can I tell, what I want apply both objects with same name by parsing json definiton? Or how is this problem solved?

Thank you, Petr

Comment: You can use a custom `JsonConverter`: in `ReadJson()`, check for both `JsonToken.StartObject` and `JsonToken.StartArray`. In the first case, use `serializer.Deserialize()`to deserialize a single object, but return a new collection (of 1 element), in the second case, deserialize to a collection directly (the opposite, in the first case, in `WriteJson()`, if needed).

Comment: Or C# translation of simple and quick C++ parser https://github.com/eltomjan/Gason

Comment: What I found - this solution need Newtonsoft.Json - exists some clear solution without third party?

Comment: You can do ~the same thing using a custom [JavaScriptConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter), override `SupportedTypes` and `Deserialize` etc. It's just a little more complex (`Json.Net` and now `System.Text.Json` are quite the standard, though. You should update you code base).

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic type

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(strAccessInRulesGet);
var items = json["items"];
```